# Нужно спарсить одну ссылку BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Нужно спарсить из конкретного div-а только одну ссылку:

```
<div class="submenu_username" style="display: none;" data-submenuid="username">
   <a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/home/">Активность</a>
   <a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/">Профиль</a>
   <a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/friends/">Друзья</a>
   <a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/groups/">Группы</a> 
   <a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/screenshots/">Контент</a> 
   <a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/badges/">Значки</a> 
   <a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/inventory/">Инвентарь</a>
</div>
```

Нужна ссылка "профиль". Пытаюсь вот так сделать, нахожу этот див

```
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
submenu = soup.find('div', class_="submenu_username")
```

а дальше всё, ступор: не пойму как именно спарсить одну ссылку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '<div class="submenu_username" style="display: none;" data-submenuid="username"><a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/home/">Активность</a><a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/">Профиль</a><a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/friends/">Друзья</a><a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/groups/">Группы</a><a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/screenshots/">Контент</a><a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/badges/">Значки</a><a class="submenuitem" href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/inventory/">Инвентарь</a></div>'
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

submenu = soup.find('div', class_="submenu_username")
```

если нужна только первая ссылка:

```
first_link = submenu.find('a')['href']
```

или все ссылки из submenu:

```
links = submenu.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    print(link['href'])
```

или сразу в список:

```
links_list = [link['href'] for link in submenu.find_all('a')]
```

и брать из него хоть первую, хоть вторую, хоть от третьей...:

```
>>> print(links_list[1])  # вторая
https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/

>>> print(links_list[2:])  # от третьей
['https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/friends/', 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/groups/', 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/screenshots/', 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/badges/', 'https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/inventory/']

>>> print(links_list[-1])  # последняя
https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573/inventory/
```

Comment: @Jacs_oS нужна вторая ссылка..

Comment: @jorkia в чем сложность из списка взять нужную по счету ссылку?

Comment: @Jacs_oS сделал вот-так `two_link = submenu.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'submenuitem'})[1].get('href')`

Comment: @Jacs_oS только почему-то в любом случае, выводит ссылку и за ней сразу ошибку https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198289451573
 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: в каком таком "в любом случае"? ;) у меня с вашим кодом ошибок нет, со своим - тоже

Comment: @Jacs_oS с любым кодом у меня ошибка. Что с вашими что с моим.

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' меняется только find_all на find если с вашим `first_link = submenu.find('a')['href']`

Comment: но ссылку выводит корректно, и после ссылки ошибка..

Comment: @Jacs_oS там `r = requests.get('https://store.steampowered.com/account/', cookie)`

Comment: список, если так `links_list = [link['href'] for link in submenu.find_all('a')]` содержит ссылки? возьмите оттуда вторую `links_list[1]`

Comment: @Jacs_oS да ссылку выдаёт, и за ней сразу ошибка.. `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Comment: не верю © создавайте *новый вопрос*, добавляйте *полностю код с вашей ошибкой*

Comment: @Jacs_oS всё хорошо работает, это мой косяк извиняюсь...